# Azure AD/Microsoft Graph API Reset User Password

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm currently building an SDK around a few key routes in the microsoft graph api using typescript. I'm hitting a route that allows me to send a PATCH to the following route using this URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{usersIdHere}
```

That PATCH requires the following body to be passed
Body:

```
{
    "passwordProfile":
    {   
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn":true,
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignInWithMfa":false,
    "password":"TestPasswordHere"
}
    }
```

All of this works and returns a 204 which is expected. My question is does this PATCH request automatically send an email with the password provided in the body? I'm currently working in a dev instance with no access to actual emails under the principal names of the users so I can't test it and want to get more clarity! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that, PATCH request **does not** send any email to the user with
> the new password. The Microsoft Graph API doesn't have **built-in**
> functionality to send password-related emails.

When I ran PATCH request to reset test user's password in [**Graph Explorer**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), I too got **same response** with 204 code like below:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/sri@xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/

{
    "passwordProfile": {
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignInWithMfa": false,
        "password": "TestPasswordHere"
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** the password change, I tried signing into that user's Outlook with **new password** like below:

[image]

As `forceChangePasswordNextSignIn` is **enabled** in PATCH request, it asked me to update the password again after signing in:

[image]

Now, I checked the user's Inbox where there is **no email** received with password provided in the body like below:

[image]

When you send a PATCH request to update the password profile of a user, it only updates the **password-related** properties for that user within the Microsoft 365 environment.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response. Do you know of a secure way that I can send the users password to them? It seems a bit redundant to give no response from the api and provide a new password when that password isn't even sent to the user. Either way, appreciate the long response, was very helpful.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not secure to send user's passwords in plain text via email. Instead, consider implementing a password reset or account recovery mechanism that allows users to securely reset their own passwords. You can post a new question specific to this requirement.